# Determine unused folder or files from react src project

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have one large react project having almost 40 folders inside src. I need to know which files and folders are not being used/imported and want to delete them.

How can I do that? Is it possible using command line?

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove all unused dependencies and it will also tells us how each dependency is used, which dependencies are useless, and which dependencies are missing from package.json you can use this npm package.

Link: https://github.com/depcheck/depcheck

But,You don't need to worry about these unused files as it will be ignored by ReactJS while creating production build.